# OpenGL performing very slowly

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

Working on a game, and I was testing out my renderer.  It unfortunately only runs at about 4 frames per second.  Profiling reveals that surprisingly, only 5% of that runtime belongs to my code, and the remaining 95% of the total run time was spent in `nvoglnt.dll`.

Only one 256x256 texture is used though, and beyond that, the only openGL code I use outside of a few camera transformations is this following template of code.  It is executed only 134217728 times for a total of 33554432 quads.

```
glTexCoord2f(u, v);
glColor3f(r, g, b);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
```

What could I be doing wrong that's causing OpenGL to become so slow?  Are there any common performance techniques I could use to improve it?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be using immediate mode (use VA's or better yet VBO's) .. but immediate mode isn't *this* slow so I guess I don't know?

Comment: Maybe it's using a software renderer.

Comment: @harold - VBO may not be viable in this case, since all the quads need to be generated based on pretty volatile data.  Unless that is, VBO memory can be changed on the fly quickly

Comment: @wormsparty - I didn't consider that... is there anyway to tell if that's the case?

Comment: @Clairvoire - Print `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` after intializing your OpenGL context.

Comment: Clairvoire: Just use reagular Vertex Arrays then, they stay in your process memory and you give OpenGL just a pointer to the data in your program.

Comment: @Clairvoire: Well, you're not going to get anything remotely like performance unless you're using fast rendering paths, which immediate mode isn't. You call 400 _million_ functions every frame, just to render. Even using client-side vertex arrays would cause a dramatic increase in performance, as you only have to call _one_ function. Data can also be [streamed to buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

Comment: @NicolBolas - Okay!  I'll begin using them.  I was unaware of additional methods of rendering, since every tutorial or OpenGL code I've seen has used this 'immediate' mode.  I assumed that was just business as usual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is executed only 134217728 times for a total of 33554432 quads.

Each of those "few" calls makes your system to switch execution context between your program and the OpenGL driver. This is not "few". Honestly I'd consider this question some fine trolling, because each and every OpenGL tutorial these days will tell you *not to use immediate mode for excactly that serious performance hit you observed, which immediate mode causes*, i.e. glBegin, glEnd, glVertex and so on.

**Use Vertex Arrays** or better yet **Vertex Buffer Objects**.

Comment: I learned OpenGL straight from the Red Book, and this is the first time I've ever heard of those two items.  Granted, I know of Display lists, but I need control over the vertices.  Will I be able to retain control of the vertex array once I give it to the driver, or will that require expensive calls as well?  (As for 'only', that might be trollin'.  It seems with C++, it's either 'never optimize' or 'why aren't you optimizing?')

Comment: Read the VBO extension. It will explain. Your point is valid: VBO were introduced later as an extension, so it is not a shame not to know about them.

Comment: OpenGL calls (unlike DX draw calls) do not cause a context switch! See http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/glsl_pseudo_instancing/docs/glsl_pseudo_instancing.pdf

Comment: @ltjax: The paper you linked is about GLSL and non-positional vertex attributes. However glVertex (which is explicitly not mentioned in that paper) will cause a context switch eventually, after all every N glVertex calls a primitive is generated.

Comment: @Clairvoire: The edition of the Red Book you're learning from must be extremely outdated then. Vertex Arrays are covered since the 2nd edition, the 3rd edition (1999) covers them in chapter 2, p. 67ff

Answer (score 4):

As datenwolf said, 134217728 is *a lot* of times. 33 million quads is even a lot if you were using vertex arrays. But modern cards should handle it pretty well.

The bottleneck here is completely the CPU, you're calling 134 million x 3 functions *every frame*. Since you're running at 4FPS. That's 1.6 billion function calls a second! No wonder it's running so slow.

What you should do is use Vertex Buffer Objects. It doesn't matter how volatile your data is, even if you have to update it every frame, it *will* be faster.

With that out of the way, I'm curious as to why you need to render 33 million volatile quads? If you give us a broader overview of what you are doing, we could propose other optimisation techniques.

Comment: Large Voxels!  1024 voxels tall, 128 wide, 128 deep.  Each voxel uses 8 quads per face to help with lighting, which I wrote to directly modify the colour attributes of each vertex.  I suppose the most effective improvement is removing obscured voxels from the rendering, but some of them are transparent, which makes it kind of tricky...

Comment: In that case, you can also look at indexed drawing, since you will reuse a lot of those vertices.

Comment: Ah! Actually I have a lot of experience with them. Removing obscured faces is a must, when generating the face of a voxel cube, check the voxel adjacent to it. If it is not air or transparent, don't generate the face! In our game this cut the geometry down to under 5% of the original. That's the biggest optimisation, but there are a few other big ones too if you're interested.